# Active Directory Change Password Permissions

Tags: powershell, active-directory

I am trying to change password (i.e entering the old password first and then the new one) with a domain admin user of another user but I am receiving the following error:

> Set-ADAccountPassword : The password does not meet the length,
>   complexity, or history requirement of the domain.

I'm using the Set-ADAccountPassword cmdlet.

What could I possibly be missing if resetting the password using the same domain admin user works just fine?

Comment: The new password you're trying to set it to isn't complex enough.  Check your policies for password complexity requirements.

Answer (score 0):

As it turns out the problem was with "Minimum Password Age" via Group Policy...